# Can “exacerbating” be used as an adjective

Tags: adjectives

I’d like to know if it’s okay to use exacerbating as an adjective in the following sentence:

“The exacerbating climate crisis calls immediate action.”

Answer (score 12):

In general, yes. My mind immediately sprang toward the collocation "exacerbating factors," for instance. See [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/366906/is-running-a-gerund-or-a-participial-adjective/366957) post for more on what exactly is happening syntactically (although the vast majority of English speakers would only know such things experientially, not academically).

For your particular sentence, though, I might recommend "worsening." Exacerbating makes it sound like the climate crisis is doing the exacerbating, not that the climate crisis is being exacerbated (e.g. by human industry), which is what I think you meant. Also, "calls for," not simply "calls."

Comment: I agree.  I checked a couple of dictionaries  and neither showed an intransitive sense for *exacacerbate*.

Comment: Agreed. "exacerbated" would also work, as that removes the agency from the climate crisis.

Comment: @gotube "exacerbated" to me would imply that there was a perfective action that made the crisis worse, i.e. a singular instance at which it became worse, rather than the imperfective progressive action implied by "worsening"

Comment: The contents of this answer are good (upvoted accordingly), but I'd suggest redrafting it, as at the moment it reads like "yes, but actually, no" which is not ideal especially if someone is only skimreading...

Comment: Upvoted for the suggestion of "worsening". To my American English ear, that sounds like the best fit of what the OP is trying to describe.

Answer (score 1):

I say "no".  We'd know what you mean, but it's odd-sounding.

Since "exacerbate" is a transitive verb, it needs a direct object ("climate change"):

> CO2 and methane emissions are **exacerbating** climate change.  Therefore, the *worsening* climate crisis calls immediate action.

Answer (score 0):

The word *exacerbating* can be used as an adjective in many contexts, such as, “the exacerbating circumstances.”

However, as a native speaker of American English, I would not say, “*The exacerbating climate crisis.”  It sounds wrong to me.  I think this might be because you use *exacerbating* to modify the thing that is **making** something worse, not the thing that is **getting** worse.  So, you would say, “the exacerbating factor of the crime,” or “the exacerbating decision for the climate crisis,” not “*the exacerbating crime” or “*the exacerbating climate crisis.”

You might instead say *worsening*, *deteriorating*, *accelerating*, *compounding*, *growing*, *burgeoning*, etc.  These all have slightly-different connotations, and *worsening* is the one that’s least likely to go wrong.